go:generate gotext with subpackages
I am following this tutorial by Alex Edwards for including translations in my Go 1.22 project. It's great, until it comes to running this command:
package translations

//go:generate gotext -srclang=en-US update -out=catalog.go -lang=en-US,it-IT github.com/myCompany/myProject/package

For what I have understood, if I want to cover more packages I just need to add them at the end, like this
package translations

//go:generate gotext -srclang=en-US update -out=catalog.go -lang=en-US,it-IT github.com/myCompany/myProject/package1 github.com/myCompany/myProject/package2 github.com/myCompany/myProject/package3

as it's said also in the tutorial

Lastly, we have the fully-qualified module path for the package(s) that you want to create translations for (in this case bookstore.example.com/cmd/www). You can list multiple packages if necessary, separated by a whitespace character.

I think it could easily become kinda ugly, since the number of packages will easily grow.
The ideal solution for me could be something like this, including all sub-packages
package translations

//go:generate gotext -srclang=en-US update -out=catalog.go -lang=en-US,it-IT github.com/myCompany/myProject/mainPackage/...

I tried passing also ./../... and similar stuff as package, but none of them works. I'm literally stuck here.
Any ideas?

Have you tried consulting the documentation of gotext as this is the program you are executing?

@Volker yep, it doesn't help. It just uses <package> or <package>* placeholders

gotext uses loader#Config.FromArgs which doesn't support wildcards.
So no, either list them all or patch gotext.
You can do //go:generate go run anything.go and build whatever list you need programatically. The source is pretty easy to copy and adapt.
